# Magento 2 - Set Cookie Expiry date using "setPublicCookie"

Tags: php-7, magento2.2.6

I am trying to set cookie based on the url params and I need to be able to assign an expiry date and the params value as well

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');

if(isset($_GET['test']) && $_GET['test'] != ""){
        $eventid = $_GET['test'];
        $expire = 60*60*24*45;
        $cookieManager->setPublicCookie('test',$eventid, $expire,"/");
}
```

But with this, I am getting Internal Server Error, and when I traced this back, I found this:

```
[26-Oct-2018 15:05:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::setPublicCookie() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata or null, integer given, called in /var/www/vhosts/********/app/design/frontend/Pearl/********/Magento_Theme/templates/html/before_body_ends.phtml on line 11 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/********/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/********/app/design/frontend/Pearl/********/Magento_Theme/templates/html/before_body_ends.phtml(11): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setPublicCookie('cjevent', 's2df23jok89gd4s...', 3888000)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/********/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/********/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/**** in /var/www/vhosts/********/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 118
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, and this solution worked for me without any problem:

```
<?php

//get cookie
if(isset($_GET['cjevent']) && $_GET['cjevent'] != ""){
    $eventid = $_GET["cjevent"];
    $expirecj = 60*60*24*45;
    setcookie("cjevent", $eventid, time()+$expirecj);
}

?>
```